# Simple grep command to search for a string not working on my ubuntu

Tags: linux, grep

I have to search for a string in a file like below using grep which is not working as expected.

It's just a simple search of the string, but not sure why it is not working

```
 echo "Naizhu NZ1020 Lady Necklace Sexy Tcollarbone Chain Alloy PlatingSilver" | grep "Lady Necklace"
```

Can somebody help me here why it's not working, want to know the reason

Comment: Can you elaborate on what doesn't work? What output do you expect. and what output do you actually get?

Comment: The match is highlighted in my shell, maybe you have some problems with coloring in your shell. Which shell/Ubuntu actually?

Comment: The code you posted works for me. I suspect there is something about the file you are searching that is breaking your process. First try `dos2unix myNonWorkingFile` and see if that fixes it. Else you'll need to make something we can copy/paste in our local environments that doesn't work. Also post the output of `file myNonWorkingFile`, maybe you have UTF8 text or something. Good luck.

Comment: @Mureinik want to search for a string in the file if it has that string in the file, print the output, like I have an example,   `LANG=C grep -i -e "Lady Necklace Sexy" filename`  for this output is not printing even though the file contains that string

Comment: @BairDev bash shell and ubuntu 16.04, no I don't have any coloring problems in my shell

Comment: @shellter if I search for string "Lady" it works for me as well, but if I search a string with spaces like above I mentioned is not working for me now. let's try like you said and will see

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The command `grep` will print the whole line matching the pattern.

So

```
echo "Naizhu NZ1020 Lady Necklace Sexy Tcollarbone Chain Alloy PlatingSilver" | grep "Lady Necklace"
```

will give you

```
Naizhu NZ1020 Lady Necklace Sexy Tcollarbone Chain Alloy PlatingSilver
```

You might use `grep -o` or `--only-matching` to

> Print only the matched (non-empty) parts of a matching line, with each
>   such part on a separate output line.

and to get only

```
Lady Necklace
```

Within the comments of the question it was mentioned that a file is used for input. Since the encoding of that is unknown currently, you may also try use character classes

```
grep -o "Lady[[:space:]]Necklace"
```

Please see `man grep` for more options.

You should also have a look into your input file and if the words you like to lookup are in the same line and separated with a space and not with other not printable characters.